# Flask и одновременно несколько подключений

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сервер, flask, backend

возникла задача написать веб приложение на flask'е, основываясь на предидущем опыте его использования знаю, что при нескольких одновременных запросах он ставит их в очередь и выполняет по мере поступления, возможно ли сделать одновременное выполнение, даже если они одинаковы?

Comment: gunicorn или uwsgi (один из них вы обязаны использовать) имеют соответствующие настройки

Comment: @andreymal бывают задачки когда нужен вэб сервер на локалхосте. для доступа к файлам и оборудованию из js, например. там сервер приложений избыточен.

Comment: @eri там и одновременное выполнение избыточно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать потоки или процессы.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
    # или
    # app.run(processes=3)
```

Пример из
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814201/can-i-serve-multiple-clients-using-just-flask-app-run-as-standalone

А вот сервер приложений, например, `gunicorn` создаст сам пул процессов и будет выдавать им запросы по мере освобождения.